# Creating a jar from a maven project in intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I created a new maven project in IntelliJ and set packaging to jar but when I build it, the target folder does not contain a jar. I'm sure its something really dumb on my part but there are just so many different things i'm reading on different websites and I just feel better asking. [image]

Comment: when you built it, did you click `Maven Projects >  Life Cycle > package` ?

Comment: @ZhongYu no, you see, this question is about using IntelliJ IDEA, so when he ***builds*** it, he does not click anything maven, because he is using IntelliJ IDEA, and he is building with IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Goto Maven Projects > Life Cycle > package then right click and from the second group choose when you want your package created. After that, whenever you Build it will remember that and automatically create your jar file.

Answer (score 46):

You should build you project using IDEA's `Maven Projects` view.

View -> Tool Windows -> Maven Projects

or open it from left bottom corner menu:

[image: menu]

And then build your project with maven goals - i.e. package:
[image: maven project]

If packaging is set to `jar` in `pom.xml`, you will get a jar in `target` dir.

Comment: I did that and it did create the jar just like I wanted to. The only thing is when I added it to the project structure of another project, I couldn't access the class from this library. I just added a SimpleUser class to test it but that wasn't showing up in my other project.

Answer (score 18):

Go to the maven project and double click clean and package.

For just do following:

[image]

Comment: this is the easiest way thanks a lot

Comment: When I tried to build with the artifacts, the JAR file is not worked correctly, but this is the easiest way and the JAR application is running without any issues. Thank You!

Answer (score 15):

You need the maven jar plugin in order to create a jar

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>add your main class</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/

Comment: I think your comment applies only to an executable jar. The OP does not mention executable.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have "jar" in packaging section of your pom.xml. You can add this before dependencies section:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Then go to View -> Tool Windows -> Maven
and in Maven window expand everything and double click on "package" in Lifecycle section.

Comment: remove the asterisks from this answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the screen-shot shows the complete pom file, you are missing the entries that define the artifact. Try adding something like this following immediately after the  tag:

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>stackoverflow-question</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

You should end up with stackoverflow-question-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar in your /target directory. You may need to refresh the directory to see it (You certainly have to in Eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You can use iu, this is my way

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]