# Jar file not in target folder after building with maven - KOTLIN

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, kotlin, vert.x

I am a JAVA developer but am trying to move to Kotlin, which tells that am new to Kotlin. I have a `kotlin` `maven` project where I implement `vertx` using `intellij` IDEA. Below is the **build** part of the pom file.

My concern is that when I build the project using the IDEA, the jar file is not generated into the `target` folder. I did follow the instructions from [kotlinlang page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html) to setup the POM file but the issue still persist.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals> <goal>test-compile</goal> </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>testCompile</goal> </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>single</goal> </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question would have been a duplicate if it was easily detected. I kept on googling and searching with different search queries until I got to [@arghtype's answer on this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30210471/6153860).

The answer suggested you specifically build the project with maven goal.
`Intellij` has a `maven projects` window on the left side of the main window which is usually minimized.

When you click and the `maven project` window opens

1. drop down the `lifecycle` and double click `clean`.
2. when cleaning is done double click again on the `package`.
3. That's all...check the target folder, you will see the jar file(s).